# File Input and Output

Tags: java, file, input, output

this is a very basic question, but can't seem to get the right answer on myProgrammingLab.

[NOT A SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enQmV.png)

Declare  a local variable  output  that is suitable for referring to an object  that provides methods  for writing to a text file.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Java, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: Screenshots not acceptable. The *text* of the code concerned and the evidence about the problem must appear *in the question itself*.

Comment: @EJP excuse my sin, I tried to fix it

Comment: The object you are probably looking for is PrintWriter

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't contain any question. So what's the problem or what do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a `PrintWriter`, which provides methods for writing to text files:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("textfile.txt");
```

To use it:

```
output.println("hello");
output.close();
```

You'll need a try/catch block for an `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks, you are the only one to have provided the answer I was looking for, I love you.